# How can I make Saga watch events before the React components are mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux-saga

If I set the browser url to: `/uni-classi-virtuali/gestisci/1`

The function `componentWillMount` of the component `DettaglioClasseVirtuale` (where I have the fetch resource call) is called before the `rootSaga` started.

Is there a standard way to make saga fetch a resource on application startup?

This my saga watcher for fetching an item of resource "classivirtualiuni":

```js
export function* watchGetClasseVirtualiUni() {
    yield takeEvery(GET_CLASSE.REQUEST, getClasseVirtualiUni)
}

export function* getClasseVirtualiUni(action) {
    try {
        const data = yield call(fetchResource, `classivirtualiuni/${action.id}`)
        if (data.success) {
            yield put(getClasse.success(data.content))
        } else {
            yield put(getClasse.failure(data.message))
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(getClasse.failure(error.message))
    }
}
```

called by a simple rootsaga:

```js
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield [
        // ...
        // ...
        watchGetClasseVirtualiUni()
    ]
}
```

This is my App class handled by react-router:

```js
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path={'/uni-classi-virtuali'} component={Main} >
                    <IndexRedirect to={'/uni-classi-virtuali/gestisci'} />
                    <Route path={'crea'} component={CreateClasseVirtualeUni} />
                    <Route path={'gestisci'} component={ClasseVirtualeList} >
                        <Route path={':id'} component={DettaglioClasseVirtuale} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path={'iscriviti'} component={IscrivitiClasseVirtuale} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the component calling the fetch data:

```js
class DettaglioClasseVirtuale extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        // dispatch the GET_CLASSE.REQUEST action
        this.fetchClasseVirtuale(this.props.classeId) 
    }

    // ...
}
```

This is the core of the application:

```js
function configureStore(initialState) {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
    let finalCreateStore = applyMiddleware(thunk, sagaMiddleware)(createStore)
    const store = finalCreateStore(reducer, initialState);
    store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run
    store.close = () => store.dispatch(END)
    return store;
}

const store = configureStore()
store.runSaga(rootSaga)

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </div>,
  document.getElementById('virtual-class')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a clean and simple workaround: putting a ready action in the rootSaga and waiting for it in the Main component.

```js
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield [
        // ...
        // ...
        watchGetClasseVirtualiUni(),
        put(ready())
    ]
}
```

```js
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Loader isLoaded={this.props.ready}>
                <Router history={browserHistory}>
                    <Route path={'/uni-classi-virtuali'} component={Main} >
                    {//...}
                    </Route>
                </Router>
            </Loader>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using react-boilerplate. I fixed it by using `compose()`.

Don't do this:

```js
import { useInjectSaga } from 'utils/injectSaga';

export function App() {
  useInjectSaga({ key: 'app', saga }); //it's already too late, we're already loading the component

  return <div />;
}

export default compose()(App);
```

Do this:

```js
import injectSaga from 'utils/injectSaga';

const key = 'app';

export function App() {
  return <div />;
}

const withSaga = injectSaga({ key, saga }); //this comes into play before the component loads

export default compose(withSaga)(App);
```

[Source](https://spectrum.chat/react-boilerplate/general/best-practices-for-app-wide-sagas~47d41658-32a8-4948-8283-0ba66b071aa3?m=MTU0ODI5NjY1NDY3MQ==)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `getClasseVirtualiUni` to your `rootSaga` which runs on app launch rather than listening to actions through `watchGetClasseVirtualiUni`. The only issue that remains is to figure out how to pass `classeId` which is passed through the component.

Comment: Thanks Rami. I used this workaround for another page which does not require a parameter. Even if I found a way to pass the parameter classeId, it remains a workaround. I was intererested in finding an actual solution